# Mouser Cart API Request

Tags: python

I don't know if I'm going to post it here but I am trying to request to the Mouser Cart API using python, and the suds library

```
def updateCart():
url = "https://mews.mouser.com/cartservice.asmx?op=UpdateCart&wsdl"
client = Client(url)
xmlns = Attribute("xmlns", "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd")
xmlnsXSD = Attribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
xmlnsXSI = Attribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
cartGUID = Attribute("CartGUID", "")
requestor = Attribute("Requestor", "richeve")

cartMessage = Element("CartMessage") \
    .append(xmlns) \
    .append(xmlnsXSD) \
    .append(xmlnsXSI) \
    .append(cartGUID)\
    .append(requestor)

partNumber = Attribute("MouserPartNumber", "941-CCS050M12CM2")
quantity = Attribute("Quantity", "5")
cartItem = Element("CartItem").append(partNumber).append(quantity)

cartMessage.append(cartItem)

xmlCartMessage = Element("xmlCartMessage").append(cartMessage)

result = client.service.UpdateCart(xmlCartMessage)
print result
print client
return True
```

The problem with this is that I always get operation timed out. I don't know if their API or  server is malfunctioning. Or I am missing something in my code.

Answer (score 2):

I just fought the python <-> Mouser cart API battle and won today. Here is what I learned.

1. The timeout is caused by an incorrect endpoint at the bottom of the WSDL. It specifies     port 9001, but there is nothing listening there. Overriding the suds client location to remove the port specification makes it work.

   ```
   url = 'https://mews.mouser.com/cartservice.asmx?WSDL'
   location = 'https://mews.mouser.com/cartservice.asmx'
   client = Client(url, location=location, cache=None)
   ```
2. `client.service.UpdateCart()` wants a *string* XML document. This is what worked for me:

   ```
   xmlCartMessage = Document()
   xmlCartMessage.append(cartMessage)
   result = client.service.UpdateCart(xmlCartMessage.plain())
   ```
3. The response from Mouser is also text—a `suds.sax.text.Text` XML fragment. See https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/suds/2011-October/001537.html for a description of this behavior. I used https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict to wrangle it into a dict.

   ```
   import xmltodict
   d = xmltodict.parse(result)
   ```